# MemoryError on dictionary variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is wrong with my code that executinon in 3rd round of `nfind` (while loop), return MemoryError in line with `CACHE[sha] = number`?
On system there is enough memory, and on the every end of the while loop I clear allocated memory, but it returns error in the 3rd run through `while` loop.
If you run these code, in some cases on, I suppose it is necessary to change `XRAN= 2**23` to greater, or smaller exponent (by one or two), to produce error.
Please help and suggestions.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from hashlib import sha256
from struct import pack
import gc

XRAN= 2**23

def compsha(number):
    return number, sha256(pack("Q", number)).digest()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gc.enable()
    nfind = 1
    while (nfind > 0):
        print(nfind)
        CACHE = {}
        pool = Pool()
        for i, output in  enumerate(pool.imap_unordered(compsha, xrange((nfind-1)*XRAN, nfind*XRAN), 2)):
            number, sha = output
            CACHE[sha] = number
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        if nfind != 0 :
            nfind = nfind + 1
        del CACHE
=======================================================
>>> 
1
2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\free_pool.py", line 20, in <module>
    CACHE[sha] = number
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Ned's answer about storing way too much in a dictionary that you don't even use, is it possible that you are running on a 32-bit python interpreter and hitting a 4GB memory limit in your main process?

```
$ python -c "import sys; print sys.maxint" // 64-bit python
9223372036854775807

$ python-32 -c "import sys; print sys.maxint" // 32-bit
2147483647
```

On windows, a 32-bit process might be limited between 2-4GB

Comment: I would say reading all the comments that this is the correct answer.  The OP seems to be saying that the program blows up at about 2GB memory usage, even though the computer has 4GB of memory.  2GB is the most likely limit for Windows I think.

Answer (score 1):

You're running out of memory because you're trying to store `2**23` elements in a dictionary.  That uses a lot of memory, apparently more than you have! You say you have enough RAM, how did you determine how much you'd need?

You'll need to come up with a different algorithm.

Also, you don't seem to ever access CACHE, so why are you using it at all?

Comment: But I free memory on every end of loop with `del CACHE`. Also I monitor memory allocation with System Explorer, and it is freed on every end of loop. There is enough memory.
in this example code `CACHE` is not used because this part is not important for this exposition.

Comment: Yea it is true that the memory is freed after every loop. It would have to be a memory limit within a single loop.

Comment: @user1391182: Can you explain why you think you have enough memory?  Clearly you don't.

Comment: If code runs once through `while` and everything is fine, on system there is in this point about half memory free (1.8 GB). So, on the every other run the situation must be the same (isn't ?), with possible some little differences. As it is visible, `pool` and `CACHE` are freed on every end of the while loop.
Also, in the point when program produce this error, they don't stop with execution. They execute up to the end of the loop, and then returns prompt to shell, but processes remain hanging with memory allocated, but with no CPU load on these processes.

Comment: It's seems that I resolved problem with last argument in `pool.imap_unordered` equal 1, instead 2.
Now it works with exponent 24.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I come back, MemErr is again present, but now on higher exponent, and on higher memory consumption, but yet not full mem usage.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind running `del CACHE` only marks that area of memory as freeable -- it doesn't actually free it. It's the garbage collector's job to come and free up that memory. Try running `gc.collect()` at the end of your loop.

(Disclosure: I can't replicate your problem so I don't know that this will fix anything)

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The advantage of reference counting is that when an object's refcount drops to zero, it can be reclaimed immediately.  The GC is for reclaiming cyclic structures.

Comment: @haldean: about replicating, try changing `XRAN = 2**23` to greater exponent, eg 24, 25 or 26. And in one point (but not in the first `while` pass), it will produce error.